# RestSharp simple complete example

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I've been trying to create a simple prototype web application that uses RestSharp to call Rest API.

I've not been able to find one good example of it. Could anyone please share and direct me to right resource please? I've already looked at following, and doesn't provide what I'm looking for i.e fully functional example:

http://restsharp.org/ (Doesn't have full application with example)

http://www.stum.de/2009/12/22/using-restsharp-to-consume-restful-web-services/ (seems to be old)

While prototyping I get the error below for code below:

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'IRestResponse' to 'RestResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  *
```

Comment: @JohnSheehan looks like twillio uses HttpClient nor restsharp

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I managed to find a blog post on the subject, which links off to an open source project that implements RestSharp.  Hopefully of some help to you.

http://dkdevelopment.net/2010/05/18/dropbox-api-and-restsharp-for-a-c-developer/
The blog post is a 2 parter, and the project is here:
https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet

It might help if you had a full example of what wasn't working.  It's difficult to get context on how the client was set up if you don't provide the code.

Comment: hi @pmms, basically I'm trying to following the code from here http://www.stum.de/2009/12/22/using-restsharp-to-consume-restful-web-services/ but I get the error which I described on my original question above.

Comment: Sorry, can't reach it from inside the corporate network.  I'll try looking later on.

Comment: OK, looking at the example, they use "var", you are using RestResponse.  Try either using "var" or IRestResponse.  They are also using a generic Execute.

Comment: Finally a decent example, cheers!

Comment: As it is now, this is a link-only answer.

Answer (score 170):

[Pawel Sawicz .NET blog](http://pawel.sawicz.eu/restsharp/) has a real good explanation and example code, explaining how to call the library;

GET:

```
var client = new RestClient("192.168.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("api/item/", Method.GET);
var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Items>>(request).Data;
```

POST:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("api/item/", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new Item
{
   ItemName = someName,
   Price = 19.99
});
client.Execute(request);
```

DELETE:

```
var item = new Item(){//body};
var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.1");
var request = new RestRequest("api/item/{id}", Method.DELETE);
request.AddParameter("id", idItem);
 
client.Execute(request)
```

The [RestSharp GitHub page](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) has quite an exhaustive sample halfway down the page. To get started install the RestSharp NuGet package in your project, then include the necessary namespace references in your code, then above code should work (possibly negating your need for a full example application).

[image: NuGet RestSharp]

Comment: This is missing parameter and headers

Comment: Your first GET example doesn't work: `The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found` `The type or namespace name 'Items' could not be found`

Answer (score 27):

Changing

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

to

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

worked for me.

Comment: or `var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;`

Comment: just to let anybody who lands here through a google search; changing to IRestResponse also helps with the typed calls. IRestResponse<DummyData> typedResponse = client.Execute<DummyData>(request); works as expected but RestResponse<DummyData> typedResponse = client.Execute<DummyData>(request); does not.

Comment: Depends on what you are returned.   for example in my case  I'm using `response.Data`     because i'm doing this   `var response = Client.Execute<List<Skill>>(request);`  In which I return   `return response.Data;`    So for me I'm actually already using IRestResponse with var because if I was explicit it would be  `IRestResponse<List<Skill>>` for response     -  Otherwise  the answer is correct !     just adding a comment