# C# Telnet Client with standard library guidelines for a simple implementation

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, telnet

I'm new with C# and I need some implementation example to do the following interactions with telnet commands/protocol

1. Connect using telnet
2. Send a command
3. Exit telnet session/connection

Describing in details the bellow steps

telnet 11.11.11.1 0000

Get https://11.11.11.1:0000/httpgw.conf?Type=SMS&Address=12345678&MsgID=12 3&Notify=N&Validity=24:00&OAdC=15555&Message=HelloBrother HTTP/1.1

^: exit

[image]

It's possible to use only the standard library or will be needed 
some custom package/library to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to do HTTP requests. For this you can use the RestSharp library that comes in the Nuget packages. Here is the link to an example on how to use RestSharp.

[RestSharp simple complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226089/restsharp-simple-complete-example)