# RestSharp get url after redirect

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, restsharp, rest

Is there a way to get the page url after redirect, with RestSharp?

For example, the code below will return page source of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226089/restsharp-simple-complete-example), but how do I get the actual URL of the thread?

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://tinyurl.com/");
        var request = new RestRequest("yydfqddw", Method.GET);
        var queryResult = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't use RestSharp in a while, bit if I remember correctly the response should have a property named ResponseUri or similar.